# Limit number of selected files 

Tags: php, html, file, select

I have a script which lets the users select multiple images while holding CTRL and then upload them to the server. I need to limit the number of selected images to 10, so when the user submits the form, he will get an error if there are more than 10 images.

How would I do this?

P.S: I have a foreach loop that looks like this:

```
foreach ($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name)
```

A PHP solution would be welcome. Since I do not trust javascript and jquery on this.

**EDIT:**

This is my script: http://pastebin.com/76NiNB6D

Comment: The problem I see with a PHP only solution is it could annoy the user if they selected 11 items and they didn't get an instant notification, with JS (jQuery or not) you could give an alert the second the 11th item is selected meaning the user can alter their selection if required before submitting an invalid set of items, you could then put in place a PHP fall back script to verify the submission is correct server side. The best of both worlds really

Comment: You have a point and I have to agree. Both PHP and JavaScript (or jQuery) would make things look better. Do I need to make another question to ask for a JavaScript solution or I can use this one to get a new answer ...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the PHP answer I was seeking myself now! :D. What I did is the following:

I checked Carlos's answer and put a variable with a value of 0 outside the loop. Then I created the errors check like Carlos did: `if ($file['error'] == 0)` Then I did again what Carlos did inside that IF Statement `$number_of_files++;`

Now I went outside the loop and did this:

```
if ($uploaded > 10)
{
    unlink($image);
    unlink($thumb);
    if ($resize) { unlink($res); }
 }
```

This deletes automatically the 11th image, and keeps just 10 images in my server.

Thanks for all the information Carlos, I think I combined it pretty well :P

Answer (score 1):

Your loop is trying to traverse a string. Maybe you meant:

```
$number_of_files = 0;
foreach ($_FILES as $file)
{
    if ($file['error'] == 0)
    {
        // file uploaded successfully
        $number_of_files++;
    }
}

if ($number_of_files > 10)
{
    die('You uploaded too many files!');
} else {
    foreach ($_FILES as $file)
    {
        if ($file['error'] == 0)
        {
             copy_the_file_to_destination(); // left as an excercise for the reader ;-)
        }
    }
}
```

You could just do `count($_FILES);`, but it would count all file inputs, even those that are empty.

Comment: Do you know if count(!empty($_FILES)) would work? If it would then this would only count the file inputs that are not empty

Comment: no, it won't work because `empty` looks for empty data and return a bool. `$_FILES` won't be empty, so it would return true (empty is not wise enough to look at every `$_FILES['*']['error']` and check if it's 0. And also, you can `count` on a non-array expression.

Comment: Beauty, thanks for that, wasn't sure in this usage so I thought I would ask rather than suggest :-)

Comment: As I used the **multiple** attribute in my _file input_, the foreach loop you showed me above wont work. It took me so long to write the foreach loop I showed in the Question, I thought a lot and tried many other methods before that (including your method), neither of them worked, except the one I showed.